# How to get an SPL token's name and symbol from its mint address?

Tags: spl-token

How do I get an SPL token's name and symbol from its mint address? There seems to be no way to do this using any of the json-rpc endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

DAS API through Helius RPC probably the easiest solution available right now

https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api

Comment: this does not work for SPL Tokens, looks like its just for NFTs

Comment: Nfts and fungible tokens on solana are all SPL tokens. Nfts are basically just mints where the decimal is 0. If the mint has metadata, the DAS API should return it. give it a try!

Comment: try the "fungible token example": https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/get-asset